# pandas loc does not preserve data type

Tags: pandas, indexing, types

Pandas `loc` indexing does not preserve the datatype of subarrays.  Consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1,2,"hi","bye"])
print(s)               # dtype: object
print(s.loc[[0]])      # dtype: object
print(type(s.loc[0]))  # <class 'int'>
```

I would like `s.loc[[0]]` to return a series with type `int`, rather than `obj` as it currently does.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the astype(original data type).astype(your prefered data type) in the print clause, e.g. from your case:

```
import pandas as pd
```

s = pd.Series([1,2,"hi","bye"])
print(s)

print(s.loc[[0]].astype(str).astype(int))

result :
0    1
dtype: int32

Here is my answer, hope it be useful

Comment: Wrap all code in tags